# Finding random index with specific value in large numpy array

Tags: python-2.7, performance, numpy, scipy

I have a very large 2D numpy array (~5e8 values). I have labeled that array using [`scipy.ndimage.label`](http://lagrange.univ-lyon1.fr/docs/scipy/0.17.1/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html) I then want to find a random index of the flattened array that contains each label. I can do this with:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import label

base_array = np.random.randint(0, 5, (100000, 5000))
labeled_array, nlabels = label(base_array)
for label_num in xrange(1, nlabels+1):
    indices = np.where(labeled_array.flat == label_num)[0]
    index = np.random.choice(indices)
```

But, it is slow with an array this large. I have also tried replacing the `np.where` with:

```
indices = np.argwhere(labeled_array.flat == label).squeeze()
```

And found it to be slower. I have a suspicion that the boolean masking is the slow part. Is there anyway to speed this up, or a better way to do this. I will say in my real application the array is fairly sparse with about 25% fill, though I have no experience with scipy's sparse array functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicion that masking separately for each label is expensive is correct, because no matter how you do it the masking will always be O(n).

We can circumvent this by argsorting by label and then randomly picking from each block of equal labels.

Since the labels are an integer range we can get the argsort cheaper than `np.argsort` by using some sparse matrix machinery available in scipy.

As my machine doesn't have an awful lot of ram I had to shrink your example a bit (factor 4). It then runs in about 5 seconds.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import label
from scipy import sparse

def multi_randint(bins):
    """draw one random int from each range(bins[i], bins[i+1])"""
    high = np.diff(bins)
    n = high.size
    pick = np.random.randint(0, 1<<30, (n,))
    reject = np.flatnonzero(pick + (1<<30) % high >= (1<<30))
    while reject.size:
        npick = np.random.randint(0, 1<<30, (reject.size,))
        rejrej = npick + (1<<30) % sizes[reject] >= (1<<30)
        pick[reject] = npick
        reject = reject[rejrej]
    return bins[:-1] + pick % high

# build mock data, note that I had to shrink by 4x b/c memory
base_array = np.random.randint(0, 5, (50000, 2500), dtype=np.int8)
labeled_array, nlabels = label(base_array)

# build auxiliary sparse matrix
h = sparse.csr_matrix(
    (np.ones(labeled_array.size, bool), labeled_array.ravel(),
     np.arange(labeled_array.size+1, dtype=np.int32)),
    (labeled_array.size, nlabels+1))
# conversion to csc argsorts the labels (but cheaper than argsort)
h = h.tocsc()
# draw
result = h.indices[multi_randint(h.indptr)]

# check result
assert len(set(labeled_array.ravel()[result])) == nlabels+1
```